# Quoting of arguments passed to Curl command in Script file

Tags: bash, curl

I have been trying to execute `curl` command from a script file.
The command is as follows (the IP address is stored in variable `ip`):

```
curl -s -X POST ${ip1} -H \"content-type: application/json\" -d \''{"args":["org1","scatest'$j$i'","27-06-2018"]}'\'
```

It's throwing an error saying "cannot read property", if I execute from the script file.

Whereas if I execute from the command line then there is no problem.
Can anybody help me out why `curl` command is not getting executed from the script file?

Comment: Please add the code where you assign your IP addresses the `ip1` variable

Comment: ip1="http://139.59.88.58:4000/invoke", this is the line for now i am setting up

Comment: Are you sure this works on the command line? The way you quote your outer quotes makes them literal and you should get an error such as "Could not resolve host: application". Or not, but your problem are the outer quotes.

Comment: this looks similar to an issue im having... Can you post the output of the command you are running?

Comment: As suggested, your escaping and quoting seems off, this would seem more appropriate: `curl -s -X POST ${ip1} -H "content-type: application/json" -d '{"args":["org1","scatest'$j$i'","27-06-2018"]}'`

Comment: Thank u Ondrej K, it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Since the discussions under the comment has lead to a solution that works well. I'm gonna put it into answer for the record and in case anyone else runs into the same pitfall.

The problem was caused by excessive quoting which would result in extra quotes being made part of the request, correct form of the command was:

```
curl -s -X POST ${ip1} -H "content-type: application/json" \
    -d '{"args":["org1","scatest'$j$i'","27-06-2018"]}'
```

Comment: If you ever take an answer from the comment section, or something that you didn't find all by your self you should remember to make it a community wiki answer.

Comment: @SheshankS. Not all by myself, but if you checked the comments (I presume, you did?), you'd see I just repeated in the answer what I've (myself) said in the comments. Still happy to update any other place if you point me in the right direction.

Comment: I did, but you should mark this as a community wiki answer, since you and Benjamin W. came up with answer, hence why you included, "As suggested, " in your answer

Comment: @SheshankS.If you believe that is the right thing to do. Honestly, not sure I fully agree with your assessment. And I was just cleaning up my queue, trying to close the issue... I also think you could have been a bit more polite about it and perhaps just ping me first? Just something to consider. Have a great one.

Comment: @SheshankS. Since the answer is apparently useful and you've incorrectly marked it as not to teach me a lessen. Since it's now a community wiki question, could you, please, remove your "not useful" vote as to not create any confusion by abusing unrelated site mechanics?

Comment: It's a community wiki answer. Editing should be easier for anyone incl. you? And IIRC votes can be retracted? Or is there a time out on that?

Comment: yes there is only ten minutes after downvoting can upvote

Comment: OK. Thanks. Still... Please, consider just telling people what you want to tell them before (incorrectly) marking stuff as useless just to presumably  scream for attention. You might be surprised you'd could get much better reception... And not cause confusion in the process.